# I have existing login info from a webforms app. Can I migrate to ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, roles, asp.net-identity

I have an existing webforms app with its own data and login info. I am working on MVC version that will use the same data. Is there a way to use the login info in the existing data base with ASP.Net Identity 2.0 in the MVC app? I have searched but find only references to MVC 4 and using existing data with simple membership. There are already usernames, passwords and emails for the few users so can Identity take advantage of that data? I need to be able to allow Admins access a certain and Editors to access another etc.

Comment: There is no simple answer here I am afraid. It all depends on how your existing user authentication/authorisation system works and how the data is being stored you may find you can use a customised/ overridden version of Identity 2.0 but again it will require some work to be able to remap all your data into the appropriate fields. You could apply the same principles from various simple membership  to Identity examples and try to apply them to your login structure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since I only have a few users in the current table, maybe it is easier to just recreate the users in Identity?

Comment: Not a problem. You could probably use the same solution if you wanted that you currently use. It is just that Microsoft have made improvements with identity provider. Again it depends on how easy it would be for you to implement it in an mvc environment. Also other considerations are how secure is it as a login system e.g. Password encryption, verification, password complexity etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to migrate to identity keeping your sql membership database as is if you want.  See: [Migrating Sql membership to identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity)  That said, if you don't have much data, might be easier just to migrate the data over to identity instead.